# Develop a mini web application to exchange books

Tags: web, content-management-system, catalog

I must develop a mini web application to exchange/resale school books (more products like school track suits and other used school items later). A tool for the parents of a school to save some money with the school supplies.

I'm an advanced programmer in .NET and I've done some medium enterprise web applications with ASPNET MVC and other .NET technologies, but now I want to be very fast developing and deploying this application, and I thought on a CMS solution with some extensions, but I have not enough time to explore the multiple solutions, so I need help to found a developed solution (or almost) with the following easy requirements:

- Every user has its own catalog and the items are public to other users of the application or public for unregistered users too.
- User: login/password, basic data
- ItemCatalog: basic data (code, name, [photos]). Specific data like year, subject, size, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've decided to use DRUPAL cms. Defining my own content type (ItemCatalog), assigning permissions to users to Create, Edit own items and query all items. I think that with some extensions I can fit all requirements.